# Heroku/Node.js - Deploying does not load CSS?

Tags: html, css, git, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a site to Heroku using node.js, and I've run into a bit of an issue. When I run my site locally, it looks as I expected it to. However, once I deploy it to Heroku, it seems that it does not recognize the CSS file I have included, despite the fact that it is using the same exact files and file structure.

I have confirmed that my HTML and CSS code is syntactically correct, and that the CSS file is being pushed through Git. I made a commit by changing one thing in the CSS to make sure that it was being pushed (it did).

Here's how I access the CSS file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

Here is an image of how the website looks locally (left) and deployed on Heroku (right) using the same exact code (the black boxes are just from me obscuring some personal details).

[Website Comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16jEE.png)

Does anyone know why Heroku refuses to use my CSS? I've been racking my brain for 2 days on this can can't figure it out.

Comment: Have you tried to access the Heroku CSS file via your browser's address bar? Are you sure the CSS file has definitely been deployed? ... you might be getting a HTTP 404 error (file not found) when you load the page? Try opening the Web Inspector in your browser and seeing if there are any 404 errors.

Comment: I don't get a 404 error, but rather it just loads the website with the only change being "/style.css" appended to the URL. The contents of the webpage do not change, and the CSS file is not shown. The Inspector shows that style.css has 0 rules, so I can assume that Heroku is not applying it (despite Git saying that the file was pushed).

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, it happend I miss one character in my whole code. Let me explain

When I heroku opened my project no css loaded, but interestingly enough jquery was working fine and the css that jquery was getting from the css file was just fine. The css file was not the problem.

Then I found that the browser was blocking some
[content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLWmp.png).
If you tell the browser to read the blocked content anyways, it will show the page no problem, but it will show a https with a horrible red line crossing it, not an option. Then I checked what content the browser was blocking
([blocked content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGW6d.png))
it was my bootstrap link.

So I was linking my bootstrap with http and not https.
I added that letter s and it is working fine now.